# Extract gcloud VM Instance Monitoring Data to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

**Outline**

We are running an ecommerce platform on Google Cloud on a dedicated VM Instance. Most of our traffic happens on Monday, as we then send our newsletters to our customer-base. Because of that we have huge traffic-peaks each Monday.

**Goal**

Because of this peak-traffic we need to make sure, that we understand how much server-load a single user is generating on average. To achieve this, we want to correlate our VM Instance Monitoring Data with our Google Analytics Data in Google Datastudio. To get a better understanding of the mentioned dynamics.

**Problem**

As far as we are aware (based on the docs), there is no direct data-consumption from the `gcloud sdk` possible in Google Datastudio. With that as a fact, we tried to extract the data via. BigQuery, but also there didn't found a possibility to access the monitoring data of our VM Instance.

Therefore we are looking for a solution, how we can extract our monitoring data of our VM Instances to Google Datastudio (preferably via BigQuery). Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific monitoring data is. But I guess you could install the [Cloud Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) or in fact any other logging library according to the [programming language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup) your application is using on the VM and [export the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#bigquery-overview)  to BigQuery, from BigQuery you could [visualize the data in Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio).

Comment: Hi @DanielOcando wee already installed the Logging & Monitoring Agent on our instance. Still I would need to get access to the full monitoring-data. But I will double check it thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-metrics-export) is Google official solution for monitoring export.

This page describes how to export monitoring metrics to bigquery dataset.

Solution deployments use pub/sub, app engine, Cloud scheduler and some python codes.

I think you only need to export the metrics listed in [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent-agent).

If you complete exporting process successfully, then you can use Google Data studio for visualizing your metric data.